# Python not recognised as an internal or external command in windows 7

Tags: python, cmd, path

I have installed python 2.7.11 from **[this](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2711/)** link and then restarted my system. However when I go to cmd and run `python --version`. It gives me an error that

> python not recognized as an internal or external command.

So I try to manually add it to my `Path variable` I see my python being installed at `C:\Python27` so I add `someotherpath;C:\Python27` to path variable and reopened `windows cmd`. But it still gives me the same error.

Is there some other way to get over with this problem.

Thanks

Comment: [link1](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/windows.html) and [link2](http://pythoncentral.io/add-python-to-path-python-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`Python2.7` contains a scripts that adds location to path for windows.

So running

```
C:\Python27\Tools\Scripts\win_add2path.py
```

solved my issue

Answer (score 2):

Changes in PATH variable do not affect already open programs. Close your command line (or powershell) window and reopen it in order to use new PATH variable.

Comment: If you configured the PATH variable correctly and it still says it can't find python, just try another restart.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Are you sure python.exe is in `C:\Python` ? and not in some other location, e.g. `C:\Python27` ? Try running python executable with full path, like: `> C:\Python\Python.exe --version`

Comment: I just copied the path from the windows url and pasted it in path variable. Also checked the formatting

Comment: Thanks @MJafarMash for help. I found an elegant solution to this.

Answer (score 2):

Please run the following command in the command prompt.

> echo %PATH%
>   It should have whatever path you have set manually. Otherwise Open a new Command prompt and try the same command.
>   Run python

If it is not working after that.

Please kindly check the Python.exe is available in *C:\Python* or Not ?

Comment: I can see it there and python.exe is present in the same folder, verified it

Comment: Can you Please run the following command C:\Python27\python.exe --version

Comment: gives me Python 2.7.11

Comment: Hence add the path for  C:\Python27 instead of C:\Python

Comment: Thanks for help, I found the solution to this

Answer (score 1):

I got same error there are two ways to solve
1)Try using py --version

2)If py is also not recognised  than uninstall python and  install it again but select the add to path option[as show in fig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOF3v.png) this time

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31548859)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to fix this is to reinstall Python and check "Add to Path" button during the installation.

Comment: I could have done it. But didn't want to unistall it . Anyways thanks for help. I found a solution